# I want to convert excel table to image in linux(ubuntu)

Tags: python, .net, excel, image, ubuntu

I want to convert my excel range to image **(for free)**. I have tried Aspose, Spire.xls, OpenXml, and many more also in python i have tried to convert DataFrame to image but there the formatting of the excel file i not converted.

So, I want a code to convert my excel file range to image using either python, DotNet, Html, Java or any. It would be helpful for me.

## Codes that i Have tried

### In DotNet

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String fileName = @"/Users/user/Downloads/Test.xlsx";
        String path = @"/Users/user/Downloads/Test.png";
        // Open the document for editing.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
             OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
             string text;
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
                 {
                     text = reader.GetText();
                     Console.Write(text + " ");
                 }
             }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            spreadsheetDocument.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }
}
```

### In Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dataframe_image as dfi
df = pd.read_excel("myexcel.xlsx")

dfi.export("mytable.png")
```

*but no styles here*

****BTW My system is a linux based ubuntu that do not support win32client and excel.interop.excel in python and DotNet respectivety.****

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: I think you may try using Aspose.Cells for Java (https://products.aspose.com/cells/java/) API but it is not free. It can convert formatted range in Excel worksheet to image fine with all the formatting/styles in tact.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AmjadSahi but i want a free convert, _i have tried it previously_.

Comment: Yes, it is not free. I am afraid, in that case (as you need free APIs), I cannot help much.